# Last cell value in a grouped by query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table related to game results with more than 300 000 records, where each row keeps player attack.
This is simplified table example. I keep an attack id, date, when attack was done, unique player id, player name (changeable by player), and result (bool value, victory or defeat).

| attack_id | date | player_id | player_name | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-09 00:00:00 | 1 | cat | 1 |
| 2 | 2024-03-10 00:00:00 | 1 | panda | 1 |
| 3 | 2024-03-11 00:00:00 | 2 | dog | 0 |
| 4 | 2024-03-12 00:00:00 | 3 | wolf | 1 |

I want to show 10 best attack players and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
player_id as id,
player_name as name,
count(attack_id) as attacks, 
sum(result) as victory,
( count(attack_id) - sum(result) ) as defeat,
( sum(result) - ( count(attack_id) - sum(result) ) ) as difference
FROM `my_table_name` 
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY difference DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Query calculates players' victories, defeats and difference between victories and defeats. The issue here related to player name. Player can change a name after some attacks, but this query returns the first player_name (related to player_id), not the last one (current).

Result of this query (according to my example, instead of cat, should be panda, because it was the last player attack name):

| id | name | attacks | victory | defeat | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | wolf | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | dog | 1 | 0 | 1 | -1 |

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8 you could use the window function ROW_NUMBEr to get the last name for a user_id

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_name (
  `attack_id` INTEGER,
  `date` datetime,
  `player_id` INTEGER,
  `player_name` VARCHAR(5),
  `result` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table_name
  (`attack_id`, `date`, `player_id`, `player_name`, `result`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2024-03-09 00:00:00', '1', 'cat', '1'),
  ('2', '2024-03-10 00:00:00', '1', 'panda', '1'),
  ('3', '2024-03-11 00:00:00', '2', 'dog', '0'),
  ('4', '2024-03-12 00:00:00', '3', 'wolf', '1');
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT
    player_id, player_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
FROM  my_table_name)
SELECT
    m.player_id as id,
    MAX(c.player_name) as name,
    count(attack_id) as attacks, 
    sum(result) as victory,
    ( count(attack_id) - sum(result) ) as defeat,
    ( sum(result) - ( count(attack_id) - sum(result) ) ) as difference
FROM `my_table_name` m JOIN CTE c ON m.player_id = c.player_id AND c.rn = 1
GROUP BY m.player_id 
ORDER BY difference DESC
LIMIT 10
```

| id | name | attacks | victory | defeat | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | panda | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | wolf | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | dog | 1 | 0 | 1 | -1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1qZX0WKL)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. But I guess there should be c.player_name as name, instead of MAX(m.player_name) as name. Max from m returns name with max amount of characters.

Comment: You are right i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Your current design has redundancy, and you should separate the name as follow:

Attack table:

- attack_id
- date
- player_id
- result

Player Table

- player_id
- player_name

This way you have a single point of entry for the player name.

Comment: Although valid, I  am not sure if it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the table like Peyman suggested is a good idea. To add to that, you could add a column to the player table called `is_current_name` and check against that. You could also add `start` and `end` time columns if you needed to refer to what name a player had at a particular time.